# JS: What keyboard keys are specified for key codes in intervals 146-185, 193-218?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keycode

What keyboard keys are specified for key codes in intervals 146-185, 193-218?

**What keys from this intervals are often used by users?**

You can get key codes from `event.keyCode` or `event.which` from `keydown` event.

For example, my keyboard has `volume up` with key code 175 and `volume down` with key code 174.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a list of *hex* key codes between 0x90 to 0xDF (144-223) which I kept for personal use. It was part of the list I gathered from many sources several years ago.

Some key names are not yet known. Unlisted keys are those that I'm not able to find any reference about them.

Note that some keys are only available on specific keyboards (language and layout dependent). Some keys are also used differently based on the keyboard (usually OEM keys).

```
Virtual Key Name     Code  Keyboard Key Name
-------------------  ----  ------------------------------------
NUMLOCK              90    NUMLOCK
                           Macintosh: NUMLOCK/CLEAR
OEM_NEC_EQUAL        92    NUMPAD = (NEC PC-9800 Normal and DP
                           Japanese keyboards)
OEM_FJ_JISHO         92    Jisho/Dictionary key
                           (Oasys and Fujitsu FMR JIS/Oyayubi
                           Japanese keyboards)
OEM_SHIFT            92    ShiftLock key (IME)
OEM_FJ_MASSHOU       93    Masshou/"Unregister Word" key
                           (Oasys and Fujitsu FMR JIS/Oyayubi
                           Japanese keyboards)
OEM_FJ_TOUROKU       94    Touroku/"Register Word" key
                           (Oasys and Fujitsu FMR JIS/Oyayubi
                           Japanese keyboards)
OEM_FJ_LOYA          95    Left Oyayubi key (Oasys and Fujitsu
                           FMR Oyayubi Japanese keyboards)
OEM_FJ_ROYA          96    Right Oyayubi key (Oasys and Fujitsu
                           FMR Oyayubi Japanese keyboards)
LSHIFT               A0    LEFT SHIFT
RSHIFT               A1    RIGHT SHIFT
LCONTROL             A2    LEFT CTRL
RCONTROL             A3    RIGHT CTRL
LMENU                A5    LEFT ALT
RMENU                A5    RIGHT ALT
BROWSER_BACK         A6    BROWSER BACK (Windows keyboards)
BROWSER_FORWARD      A7    BROWSER FORWARD (Windows keyboards)
BROWSER_REFRESH      A8    BROWSER REFRESH (Windows keyboards)
BROWSER_STOP         A9    BROWSER STOP (Windows keyboards)
BROWSER_SEARCH       AA    BROWSER SEARCH (Windows keyboards)
BROWSER_FAVORITES    AB    BROWSER FAVORITES
                           (Windows keyboards)
BROWSER_HOME         AC    BROWSER HOME (Windows keyboards)
VOLUME_MUTE          AD    VOLUME MUTE (Windows keyboards)
VOLUME_DOWN          AE    VOLUME DOWN (Windows keyboards)
VOLUME_UP            AF    VOLUME UP (Windows keyboards)
OEM_FJ_000           B0    NUMPAD 000 (Oasys and Fujitsu FMR
                           JIS/Oyayubi Japanese keyboards)
MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK     B0    MEDIA NEXT TRACK (Windows keyboards)
OEM_FJ_EQUAL         B1    NUMPAD = (Fujitsu and Oasys Japanese
                           keyboards)
MEDIA_PREV_TRACK     B1    MEDIA PREVIOUS TRACK
                           (Windows keyboards)
OEM_FJ_00            B2    NUMPAD 00 (Oasys and Fujitsu FMR
                           JIS/Oyayubi Japanese keyboards)
MEDIA_STOP           B2    MEDIA STOP TRACK (Windows keyboards)
MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE     B3    MEDIA PLAY/PAUSE (Windows keyboards)
OEM_OAS_1            B4    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
LAUNCH_MAIL          B4    LAUNCH MAIL (Windows keyboards)
OEM_OAS_2            B5    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT  B5    LAUNCH MEDIA SELECT
                           (Windows keyboards)
OEM_OAS_3            B6    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
LAUNCH_APP1          B6    LAUNCH APPLICATION 1
                           (Windows keyboards)
OEM_OAS_4            B7    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
LAUNCH_APP2          B7    LAUNCH APPLICATION 2
                           (Windows keyboards)
OEM_OAS_5            B8    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_6            B9    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_0                B9    ??? key (IME)
OEM_1                BA    OEM key.
                           US standard keyboards: (;:)
OEM_PLUS             BB    OEM PLUS key.
                           Any standard keyboards: (=+)
OEM_COMMA            BC    OEM COMMA key.
                           Any standard keyboards: (,<)
OEM_MINUS            BD    OEM MINUS key.
                           Any standard keyboards: (-_)
OEM_PERIOD           BE    OEM PERIOD key.
                           Any standard keyboards: (.>)
OEM_2                BF    OEM key.
                           US standard keyboards: (/?)

OEM_3                C0    OEM key.
                           US standard keyboards: (`~)
ABNT_C1              C1    ??? key
OEM_OAS_7            C1    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
ABNT_C2              C2    ??? key
OEM_OAS_8            C2    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_9            C3    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_10           C4    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_11           C5    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_12           C6    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_13           C7    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_14           C8    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_15           C9    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_16           CA    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_17           CB    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_18           CC    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_19           CD    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_20           CE    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_21           CF    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_22           D0    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_23           D1    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_24           D2    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_25           D3    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_26           D4    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_27           D5    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_28           D6    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_OAS_29           D7    ??? key (Oasys Japanese keyboards)
OEM_4                DB    OEM key.
                           US standard keyboards: ([{)
OEM_5                DC    OEM key.
                           US standard keyboards: (\|)
OEM_6                DD    OEM key.
                           US standard keyboards: (]})
OEM_7                DE    OEM key.
                           US standard keyboards: ('")
OEM_8                DF    ??? OEM key
```

Comment: About your `???`: there is nothing “questionable” about `ABNT_*` ones.  Look to-the-left-of-`RSHIFT` and below-the-`Gray-+` in [the standard Brazilian (ABNT2) layout](https://kbdlayout.info/KBDBR/virtualkeys).  It is also [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_keyboard_layout#Brazil).

Comment: To see where some “funny” keys may come from, observe [an industrial keyboard](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=60355.0) from [a huge family made by Fujitsu](https://telcontar.net/KBK/Fujitsu/series).  (Although I have no clue where, for example, `OEM_OAS_25`  would be positioned!

Comment: `???` denotes "unknown". Not "questionable". It's odd & unique nevertheless, since, while the physical key has the same label as e.g. US keyboard which is `/` `?`, the key has different scan code and Windows virtual key code.

Comment: First of all, I did not write «questionable», but «“questionable”» .  Second, it seems that you are looking at key/VK assignment in a wrong way…  Look: the key to the right of `.>` is `OEM_2` — as expected!  **An extra** key to the right of it *happens to be marked* as `/?` indeed.  But it is “an `OEM` key” anyway — in national keyboards there may be “no expectation” about what characters they are going to be assigned…!  (But obviously, you should know all of this…)